# How to Get Product Id And Value in Custom Log

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3

I am tired, please help me, to get product id and value when i add product to cart. through event or any other method in custom log   magento 2

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Vendor\Cart\Observer\CartLog" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then Create an Observer file -

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Cart\Observer;
 
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
 
    class CartLog implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
            $logger = new \Zend_Log();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info($item->getProduct->getId());
            }
        }
 
    }
```

Hope it helps!!